# How to perfectly align 2 scanned multiple choice paper images? (Matlab)

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, alignment, compare

Is there a way to align 2 scanned multiple choice paper images? Maybe by using a bar code to auto align them or using a specific shape so that I can compare or find the differences in the answers between the two papers in Matlab?

This is the [reference image](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=24pmgbb&s=6).

This is the [image I want to alter](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2ntjqiq&s=6) which will overlay the reference image.

Comment: welcome to stack-overflow, the website where you show us the **what you have tried** (i.e. code) and then we help you out.

Comment: This is more of an algorithms question and not a programming question, consider asking at http://dsp.stackexchange.com

Comment: Mathematica is funny: `ImageCompose[
 ImageAlign[f = Import["http://oi45.tinypic.com/24pmgbb.jpg"], 
  Import["http://oi47.tinypic.com/2ntjqiq.jpg"]], {f, .5}]`, gives http://i.imgur.com/Z3EKG.png

Comment: @mmgp very straightforward, +1

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is sometimes called "rigid image registration" and there are many packages that address this problem. Check out for example the following on MATLAB central.

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19086-automatic-2d-rigid-body-image-registration

"rigid" is here as opposed to "elastic", so only translation and rotation, but no stretching is considered, since you work with paper.